# How can I call my function as a command line without segmentation fault?

Tags: c

I have a code called `unscramble` that takes two files, `Jumbled.txt` and `dictionary.txt` and finds if any words contain the same characters in both the files or not, for instance, here is a sample input for

```
Jumbled.txt:                                  
Hello
Wassup
Rigga
Boyka
Popeye

dictionary.txt:
olleH
Yello
elloH
lloeH
aggiR
ggiRa
giRag
yokaB
Bakoy
kaBoy
eyePop
poePye
```

and the output of the code above is:

```
Hello: olleH elloH lloeH
Wassup: NO MATCHES
Rigga: aggiR ggiRa giRag
Boyka: yokaB Bakoy kaBoy
Popeye: eyePop poePye
```

Here is my code that attempts to solve it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_WORD_LENGTH 50
#define MAX_NUM_WORDS 500000

int compare_char(const void *a, const void *b) {
    return *(char*)a - *(char*)b;
}

void sort_word(char *word) {
    qsort(word, strlen(word), sizeof(char), compare_char);
}

int is_valid_word(char *jumbled_word, char *word) {
    char sorted_jumbled_word[MAX_WORD_LENGTH];
    char sorted_word[MAX_WORD_LENGTH];
    strcpy(sorted_jumbled_word, jumbled_word);
    strcpy(sorted_word, word);
    sort_word(sorted_jumbled_word);
    sort_word(sorted_word);
    return strcmp(sorted_jumbled_word, sorted_word) == 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("Usage: unscramble <dictionary> <jumbles>\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    char *dict_filename = argv[1];
    char *jumbles_filename = argv[2];

    char dictionary[MAX_NUM_WORDS][MAX_WORD_LENGTH];
    int num_words = 0;
    FILE *dict_file = fopen(dict_filename, "r");
    if (dict_file == NULL) {
        printf("Error: Could not open dictionary file %s\n", dict_filename);
        exit(1);
    }
    char line[MAX_WORD_LENGTH];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), dict_file) != NULL) {
        // Remove trailing newline character
        line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0';
        // Copy word into dictionary
        strcpy(dictionary[num_words], line);
        num_words++;
    }
    fclose(dict_file);

    // Loop over jumbled words file
    FILE *jumbles_file = fopen(jumbles_filename, "r");
    if (jumbles_file == NULL) {
        printf("Error: Could not open jumbled words file %s\n", jumbles_filename);
        exit(1);
    }
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), jumbles_file) != NULL) {
        line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0';
        char sorted_word[MAX_WORD_LENGTH];
        strcpy(sorted_word, line);
        sort_word(sorted_word);
        int found_match = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < num_words; i++) {
            if (is_valid_word(sorted_word, dictionary[i])) {
                if (!found_match) {
                    printf("%s:", line);
                    found_match = 1;
                }
                printf(" %s", dictionary[i]);
            }
        }
        if (!found_match) {
            printf("%s: NO MATCHES", line);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    fclose(jumbles_file);

    return 0;
}
```

However, after converting it into executable format and checking that Jumbled.txt AND dictionary.txt is available in the same directory, I get this error message:

```
xxxxxxxxx@LAPTOP-xxxxxxxx:~$ gcc -Wall -W -pedantic -o unscramble unscramble.c  
xxxxxxxxx@LAPTOP-xxxxxxxx:~$ vim Jumbled.txt
xxxxxxxxx@LAPTOP-xxxxxxxx:~$ vim dictionary.txt
xxxxxxxxx@LAPTOP-xxxxxxxx:~$ vim unscramble.c
xxxxxxxxx@LAPTOP-xxxxxxxx:~$ ./unscramble dictionary.txt Jumbled.txt
Segmentation fault
xxxxxxxxx@LAPTOP-xxxxxxxx:~$
```

what should I change and what is my problem?

**Edit** What I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_WORD_LENGTH 50
#define MAX_NUM_WORDS 500000

int compare_char(const void *a, const void *b) {
    return *(const char*)a - *(const char*)b;
}

void sort_word(char *word) {
    qsort(word, strlen(word), sizeof(char), compare_char);
}

int is_valid_word(const char *jumbled_word, const char *word) {
    char sorted_jumbled_word[MAX_WORD_LENGTH];
    char sorted_word[MAX_WORD_LENGTH];
    strcpy(sorted_jumbled_word, jumbled_word);
    strcpy(sorted_word, word);
    sort_word(sorted_jumbled_word);
    sort_word(sorted_word);
    return strcmp(sorted_jumbled_word, sorted_word) == 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("Usage: unscramble <dictionary> <jumbles>\n");
        return 1;
    }
    char *dict_filename = argv[1];
    char *jumbles_filename = argv[2];

    char (*dictionary)[MAX_WORD_LENGTH] = malloc(MAX_NUM_WORDS * sizeof(*dictionary));
    if(!dictionary) {
        printf("Error: malloc failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int num_words = 0;
    FILE *dict_file = fopen(dict_filename, "r");
    if (dict_file == NULL) {
        printf("Error: Could not open dictionary file %s\n", dict_filename);
        return 1;
    }

    char line[MAX_WORD_LENGTH];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), dict_file) != NULL && num_words < MAX_NUM_WORDS) {
        // Remove trailing newline character
        line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0';
        // Copy word into dictionary
        strncpy(dictionary[num_words], line, MAX_WORD_LENGTH - 1);
        num_words++;
    }
    fclose(dict_file);

    // Loop over jumbled words file
    FILE *jumbles_file = fopen(jumbles_filename, "r");
    if (jumbles_file == NULL) {
        printf("Error: Could not open jumbled words file %s\n", jumbles_filename);
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), jumbles_file) != NULL) {
        // Remove trailing newline character
        line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0';
        if (strlen(line) > MAX_WORD_LENGTH - 1) {
            printf("Error: Jumbled word %s is too long\n", line);
            continue;
        }
        char sorted_word[MAX_WORD_LENGTH];
        strcpy(sorted_word, line);
        sort_word(sorted_word);
        int found_match = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < num_words; i++) {
            if (is_valid_word(sorted_word, dictionary[i])) {
                if (!found_match) {
                    printf("%s:", line);
                    found_match = 1;
                }
                printf(" %s", dictionary[i]);
            }
        }
        if (!found_match) {
            printf("%s: NO MATCHES", line);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    fclose(jumbles_file);

    free(dictionary);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have already seen a question with this exact set of words, but the attempted solution was totally different. Have you tried this before, or was it your classmate? Just curious.

Comment: @n.m. it was me lol, I asked the same question previously but I wrote up my own code, now I'm dealing with a seg error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first step is to run your program in a debugger to figure out where it segfaults:

```
$ gcc -g3 -Wall -W -pedantic -o unscramble unscramble.c
$ gdb ./unscramble
(gdb) set args dictionary.txt Jumbled.txt
(gdb) r
(gdb) bt
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00005555555552c6 in main (argc=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7ffffe82657c>, argv=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7ffffe826570>) at 1.c:26
26      int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
```

This is strange, i.e. memory corruption, before even starting, so you look at allocations and you see:

```
    char dictionary[MAX_NUM_WORDS][MAX_WORD_LENGTH];
```

which is 500k * 50 bytes or 25 MB.  The default stack on my system is 8 MB.  You could up your stack size with, say,  `ulimit -s 30000`, and your program would run as it.  It would be better to reduce memory usage, or use `malloc()` to allocate space on the heap instead:

```
    char (*dictionary)[MAX_WORD_LENGTH] = malloc(MAX_NUM_WORDS * sizeof(*dictionary));
    if(!dictionary) {
        printf("malloc failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    // ...
    free(dictionary);
```

and it now returns:

```
Hello: olleH elloH lloeH
Wassup: NO MATCHES
Rigga: aggiR ggiRa giRag
Boyka: yokaB Bakoy kaBoy
Popeye: eyePop poePye
```

Comment: I've done as you said but there is still a segmentation fault, I've tried to debug my code as well and did some error handling but to no avail. I've edited my original question to show what I have now after the error handling and after putting in what you've said. It's still segmentation error when I run it on Ubuntu

Comment: I cannot reproduce the segfault with revised code. Are you sure you rebuild your program? If so, then I suggest you submit a new question with a stacktrace as it's a different problem with revised code. I added details above on how to get a stacktrace.

Comment: did you create two text files, Jumbled.txt and dictionary.txt and then do ./unscramble dictionary.txt Jumbled.txt ?

Comment: also I did create a new question as you said

Comment: Yes, both directly and via gdb as noted above.

Comment: Good job, from my perspective, you can accept the question but it also makes sense that you wait of the outcome of the new question.  I suggest you remove the "Edit What I have so far:" and revised code from the question as not to confuse others.

Answer (score 1):

You put the `dictionary` array in `main`, so this array is going to live on `main`' s function stack; that's approximately 23.8M on the stack, over the usual stack size limit of almost all the operating systems (8M on Linux).

If you still want to use a bi-dimensional array, put this array outside `main` as a global variable, so it won't live on `main`'s stack frame anymore. Alternatively use `malloc` to allocate this array, so it lives in the program's heap. See [What and where are the stack and heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap)